# Aerospike where query index python

Tags: python, aerospike, nosql

We are currently testing "aerospike".
But there are certain points in the documentation that we do not understand with reference to the keys.

```
key = ('trivium', 'profile', 'data')
# Write a record
client.put(key, {
    'name': 'John Doe',
    'bin_data': 'KIJSA9878MGU87',
    'public_profile': True
})
```

We read about the namespace, but when we try to query with the general documentation.

```
client = aerospike.client(config).connect()
        query = client.query('trivium', 'profile')
        query.select('name', 'bin_data')
        query.where(p.equals('public_profile', True))
        print(query.results())
```

The result is null, but when we eerase the "where" statement the query brings all the records, the documentation says that the query work with the secondary index, but how that works?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one filter in a query. That filter, in your case, the equality filter, is on the public_profile bin. To use the filter, you must build a secondary index (SI) on public_profile bin, however SIs can only be on bins containing numeric or string data type. So to do what you are trying to do, change public_profile to a numeric entry say 0 or 1, then add a secondary index on that bin and use the equality filter on the value of 0 or 1.  While you can build multiple SIs, you can only invoke one filter in a any given query. You cannot chain multiple filters with an "AND". If you have to use multiple filters, you will have to write Stream UDFs (User Defined Functions).  You can use AQL to define SIs, you just have to do once.

```
$aql
aql>help  --- see the command to add secondary index.
aql>exit
```

SIs reside in process RAM. Once defined, any new data added or modify is automatically indexed by aerospike as applicable. If you define index on public_profile as NUMERIC but in some records insert string data in that bin, those records will not be indexed and won't participate in the query filter.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer, you are right i figured that, Aerospike is fast, we thought that we can use it for User Administrator, but seems like the make of a complex query it's some important for the system. However we'll try another tech like mongo or cassandra.

Thanks a lot, regards

Comment: Sure, you should use the solution that best fits your use case. BTW, stream udfs are pretty easy to write. Here is a quick example. https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/record-manipulation-with-more-than-one-filter-lua/3637  and code is here: https://github.com/pygupta/aerospike-discuss/tree/master/topic3637

Comment: Updated github link: https://github.com/pygupta/aerospike-discuss/tree/master/topic3637_streamUDF_multifilter